# How to show message when Task fails due to Timeout

Tags: swift

I need a clean way for this example to print("ERROR") when the task ends due to the timeout.

```
func getUserDataService() -> Bool{
    var getDataStatus = false

    //Create the url with NSURL
    let url = URL(string: "http://someurl")! //change the url

    //Create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //Now create the URLRequest object using the url object
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.timeoutInterval = 15

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {


                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {

                        getDataStatus = true

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
    return getDataStatus
}
```

It prints the following when it fails, but I'm not sure where to control this.

> 2019-05-27 13:53:58.501322-0400 AppName[60195:841789] Task <AB410EF3-5520-44AD-A458-DD75D1F6AD09>.<3> finished with error - code: -1001
>   2019-05-27 13:53:58.505525-0400 AppName[60195:842001] Task <AB410EF3-5520-44AD-A458-DD75D1F6AD09>.<3> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation [URL Loading System Error Codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes). The timeout error is `-1001` aka `NSURLErrorTimedOut`

The error is returned in the completion handler of the data task. Handle it!

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    if let nserror = error as NSError?,
      nserror.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
      // do something
      return
    }
```

Apart from that you cannot return a `Bool` value from that method, you have to add a completion handler

```
func getUserDataService(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

...
```

And call

```
completion(true)
```

and delete

```
return getDataStatus
```

Comment: Thank you @Vadian now I'm not sure how to call that function to check if is true or false.